# is it possible to execute some javascript on a page without manually adding it to the page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

The situation is as follows - there is a page A.aspx which has a hyperlink to another page B.aspx
I want to run some javascript after someone clicks on the hyperlink in A.aspx and after B.aspx loads BUT I do not want to manually add this javascript to B.aspx?

The background for this is as follows- 
In a sharepoint site collection all the pages use a masterpage but there can be some pages which are standalone and these don't use a masterpage. The task is to add javascript to every page in the site (standalone as well as regular). So I added this javascript to the masterpage but since these standalone pages don't use the masterpage, they are not loading the javascript. The situation is that some regular sharepoint pages have hyperlinks pointing to these standalone pages, so when someone clicks on the hyperlink on the regular sharepoint page the standalone page gets loaded. Since there are quite a lot of standalone pages and I don't want to touch them, I am thinking if there is any way to execute javascript on these pages after they load (as a result of a user clicking the hyperlink on the regular sharepoint page) ?

Comment: `B.aspx` has to load that script by itself. However if both pages have the same domain and `B.aspx` is opened via `window.open` then you can indeed execute scripts in `B.aspx` from `A.aspx`.

Comment: @Derek do you have any pointers about go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run some javascript after someone clicks on the hyperlink in A.aspx and after B.aspx loads BUT I do not want to manually add this javascript to B.aspx

You can't do that, no. (Not without requiring everyone to have a browser extension installed.) I'm afraid unpalatable as it is, if the standalone pages don't already have a script they load that you could add this new code to, you'll have to modify each of the standalone pages to include the new script.

> I checked just now - the hyperlinks are like this  `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPopUpPage('B.aspx?ItemID=65','',500,350);">test link</a>` they seem to be using `OpenPopUpPage`

That's a *completely* different thing. *If* the `OpenPopUpPage` is using `window.open`, and the `A.aspx` page sticks around while `B.aspx` opens, it's possible for code in `A.aspx` to do things with the `B.aspx` page when it opens (assuming they're on the same origin, which presumably they are in your case).

You'll need to find the source of `OpenPopUpPage` and find its call to `window.open`, hook an event on the resulting window (`DOMContentLoaded` or, worst case, `load`), and then make your modifications to the page in the event handler:

```
var url = "B.aspx";
var wnd = window.open(url);
checkChildReady();
function checkChildReady() {
    if (wnd.document && String(wnd.document.location).indexOf(url) != -1) {
        if (wnd.document.readyState != "loading") {
            windowReady();
        } else {
            wnd.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", childReady, false);
        }
    }
}
function childReady() {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder what you think about the comment made above by Derek ? the pages (regular and standalone) share the same domain and I am guessing that the standalone pages open via window.open

Comment: @vivekm: What do you mean you're "guessing" that they're opened with `window.open`? Can't you look? But in the question, you said it was a link from one page to the next and you wanted to execute code on the target after the user followed the link. That's a completely different scenario to `window.open`. It's that sceanrio the answer applies to.

Comment: @t-j-crowder I said I am guessing because I am not really sure whether window.open is used when a hyperlink is clicked or the standalone page opens by some other mechanism. I will have to check.

Comment: @t-j-crowder I checked just now - the hyperlinks are like this   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="OpenPopUpPage('B.aspx?ItemID=65','',500,350);">test link</a>   they seem to be using OpenPopUpPage

Comment: @vivekm: That's completely different from normal link processing. I've added a note about it to my answer.

Comment: @t-j-crowder Although it is little late, thank you very much for your note. The OpenPopUpPage seems to be a sharepoint OOTB javascript so I don't think I will be able to mess with that. So far I have not been able to locate that OpenPopPage javascipt code but I will keep digging. If I find it, I will post that code here